# How to format selected code using vscode and Prettier?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have add Prettier in my VScode but I want to format my code only when I highlight my code,
say

```
let a = [1, 2, 3,          4]; (line1)

let b = [          1,2 ,3,4]; (line3)
```

how can I just format line 1 when I highlight line 1 only and the result should be

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; (line1)

let b = [          1,2 ,3,4]; (line3)
```

## thanks

UPDATE:
I know we can format the code in a code block. But what I want to do is

```
const test = (a, b,          c) => {  (line 1)
  console.log("show a",          a);   (line 2)
  console.log("show b",     b);   (line 3)
}
```

## If I highlight `b,          c` in line 1 and format it. It only formats the code in line 1 but not 2 and 3

futher update:
[this is my vscode shortcut setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8lwT.png)

[when I highlight like this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kphKC.png)

[it becomes like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7c4W.png)

Answer (score 1):

Select the code you want to format and press CTRL + SHIFT + P to open the command pallette. Then type in "format" and select format selected code. Or you can select your code and press right click which should bring up a context menu where you can select the option

Comment: I have tried this method before, but seems it will also changes my other code. say I write a function that used 10 lines. I only want to format line 8 to line 10 (even line 3 is also weird). So I highlight line 8 to 10 and format it. And it still formats the code in line 3 {but the code outside the function is not be changed}.

Comment: Then you should use CTRL + K then CTRL + F

Answer (score 1):

Select the code or leave the cursor in the row you want to format and press `Ctrl + K Ctrl + F`.

Comment: As my 'update' mentioned before. I also tried this but it will affect the other code that I have not highlighted...

Comment: I did it on my vscode, it works. Make sure you don't change default keyboard shortcuts, press ```Ctrl + K Ctrl + S``` then search ```format``` to check it

Comment: I have a update my question with my setting and some example. I am not sure what makes my vscode cannot do the same thing...

Comment: The possibility in the ```prettier``` config, maybe it's already formatted before your vscode auto-save

Comment: I have disable the on save setting. When I select `console.log("b",       b)` and format this line, the `const test = (a, b    , c) => {` part won't be format...

Answer (score 1):

*I dont know the solution yet, but there are some info that may help.*

- Basically, there are **something wrong with the linter**. ( https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/137 )

  And your may **fix** it by checking out this https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html ,

<sub>- I dont know how & didnt try. cuz:: [[

  - looks complicated (download many things) & mess up with the project structure
  - may not even work
  - some info I have no knowledge of / incompatible with my understanding
  - dont know what will happen to my linters
  - dont know what is the next step</sub>






<sub>> []
>
> https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/134
>
> []
>
> No, the issue is with `prettier-eslint` not supporting range formatting.
>
> ...
>
> I would suggest switching to the [recommended approach of integrating ESLint and Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#linter-integration)
>
> https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/137
>
> []
>
> let Prettier do the formatting and configure the linter to not deal with formatting rules. You can find instructions on how to configure each linter on the Prettier docs site.
>
> ...
>
> For details refer to the [Prettier documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html).
>
> https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#linter-integration
>
> []
>
> Linters usually contain not only code quality rules, but also stylistic rules. Most stylistic rules are unnecessary when using Prettier, but worse – they might conflict with Prettier! Use Prettier for code formatting concerns, and linters for code-quality concerns, as outlined in [Prettier vs. Linters](https://prettier.io/docs/en/comparison.html).
>
> Luckily it’s easy to turn off rules that conflict or are unnecessary with Prettier, by using these pre-made configs:
>
> - [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier)
> - [stylelint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/stylelint-config-prettier)
>
> https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html
>
> []
>
> I would like to format my code with prettier, then apply all eslint fixes. Previously, this could be achieved by setting prettier.eslintIntegration to true. Now, the extension say that this option is [*DEPRECTAED*] and prettier-eslint should be used instead. However, it's not clear how to use prettier-eslint in vscode.
>
> https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/999</sub>

---

*Actually, "format only selected code" is working on my end, I didnt do any fancy extra config.*

- What you need to pay attention to is the "syntax tree"

  -- ie: **dont blindly select across the `scope (the bracket {})`**.

  @eg::

  - given

    ```js
    function test() {
      let a = [1, 2, 3,          4];

      let b = [          1,2 ,3,4]; // select only this line

      return false
    }
    ```
  - if you **only** select::

    ```js
    let b = [          1,2 ,3,4];
    ```

    then press `ctrl+k, ctrl+f`

    everything is **fine**
  - if you select **across** the bracket (the `}` for function scope)::

    ```js
      let b = [          1,2 ,3,4]; // select only this line

      return false
    }
    ```

    then press `ctrl+k, ctrl+f`

    the **whole thing in the bracket  (the `}` for function scope)** gets formatted
- the "syntax tree" in a **`class`** is a bit weird.

  -- ie: if you select the **WHOLE function AA** & format it -- codes inside **another function BB** will also get formatted...

  you may need to apply **`// prettier-ignore`** somewhere to prevent formatting
- prettier-ignore

  > A JavaScript comment of `// prettier-ignore` will exclude the next node in the abstract syntax tree from formatting.
  >
  > https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

  - (note, it seems there is no ending tag for `// prettier-ignore` for Javascript (at current stage of Prettier))
  - for the meaning of a **"syntax tree"**, see ex below

    - if you place it **above** the code line 
      seems it applies to the item (the code) (-- which is a "syntax tree node") **directly below** ((empty lines not counted for)) the `// prettier-ignore` line 
      -- eg-below: `console.log("show a",          a);`, and **ends** there.
    - if you place it behind the code line (**inline**) 
      seems it applies to the inline code only
- @for_your_case-do_this:

  ```js
  const test = (a, b,          c) => {  
    // prettier-ignore
    console.log("show a",          a);  
    // prettier-ignore
    console.log("show b",     b);  
  }

  // or
  const test = (a, b,          c) => {  
    console.log("show a",          a); // prettier-ignore
    console.log("show b",     b); // prettier-ignore
  }
  ```